# High bandwidth, high latency file transfer in Windows

Tags: networking, server-message-block

We're attempting to transfer some SQL backup files (~5-75GB each) across a network with about 70ms latency between two servers (Server 2012 R2 - same domain) across a VPN connection.

Both servers are on the same domain.  Using iperf with a large window size (1MB+), we can achieve a consistent 50mbps+ transfer rate.  With smaller windows and multiple threads, we are able to achieve similar bandwidth maximums (~16 threads at ~3mbps).

Using both Windows Explorer and Robocopy to transfer the files, we are unable to exceed 200-300KBps (1.5-2mbps) consistently.  Is there any way to tweak the sending TCP window size for this or other suggestions to try?

I saw some similar posts with high latency / high bandwidth networks from 5+ years ago, but they were all targeting older operating systems.